# Как можно сделать вертикальное подменю всплывающим над основным меню?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
    <div id="menu_left" class="grad">    
    <ul class="first_level">                
        <li class="item_menu"><span class="line_menu"></span><a href="#" class="f_level_link">1111111111</a>                        
            <ul class="second_level" style="">                                
                <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="#">2222222</a></li>
                <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="#">2222222</a></li>        
                <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="#">2222222</a></li>            
            </ul>
        </li>  
        <li class="item_menu"><span class="line_menu"></span><a href="#" class="f_level_link">1111111111</a>                        
            <ul class="second_level" style="">                                
                <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="#">2222222</a></li>
                <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="#">2222222</a></li>        
                <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="#">2222222</a></li>            
            </ul>
        </li>  
        <li class="item_menu"><span class="line_menu"></span><a href="#" class="f_level_link">1111111111</a>                        
            <ul class="second_level" style="">                                
                <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="#">2222222</a></li>
                <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="#">2222222</a></li>        
                <li class="sub_item_menu"><a href="#">2222222</a></li>            
            </ul>
        </li>  
    </ul>
</div>

    #menu_left {width:250px; display: block; float: left; position: relative;  margin-bottom: 10px;  padding: 5px 0;} 
    #menu_left li a {text-decoration:none; text-transform: uppercase; position: relative;}
    #menu_left ul li a :hover {font-color:#007080;}
    #menu_left .item_menu:first-child .line_menu{border-top:none;} 
    #menu_left .item_menu>a {font: 15px  Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; color:black;font-weight: 700; padding-left: 24px; line-height:40px; display: block;zoom:1;}   
    #menu_left .item_menu a:hover{color: #f9648e;}
    #menu_left .second_level { margin: 0; padding-left: 23px;background: #F8F8F8; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#F8F8F8), to(#e6e6e6)); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F8F8F8, #e6e6e6); background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F8F8F8, #e6e6e6); background: -ms-linear-gradient(#F8F8F8, #e6e6e6); background: -o-linear-gradient(#F8F8F8, #e6e6e6); background: linear-gradient(#F8F8F8, #e6e6e6); -pie-background: linear-gradient(#F8F8F8, #e6e6e6);}
    #menu_left .sub_item_menu  { border: none;text-indent: -0.1em; *text-indent: -0.1em;padding: 3px 10px 3px 12px;position: relative;} 
    #menu_left .sub_item_menu a { color: #000; font-size:13px;text-transform: none; text-decoration: none;border-bottom: 1px solid #f9648e;
    line-height: 19px;} 
    #menu_left .sub_item_menu a:hover {font-size:13px; border-bottom: none;}

     /*#menu_left .sub_item_menu {display: none;}​​   подменю  */​​​​​​​
```

Добрый вечер, как можно сделать вертикальное подменю всплывающим над основным меню? Смысл такой, вертикальное меню не должно изменять высоту (1111), подменю (2222) должно всплывать при навидение поверх меню (1111) 
[Cсылка](http://jsfiddle.net/Hancock_888/zDbrG/) для примера.

Answer (score 1):

Если обойтись только CSS-средствами не получится, то [можно таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/zDbrG/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.item_menu ul {display:none;}
.item_menu:hover{position:relative;}
.item_menu:hover ul{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;display:block;}
```